# Directive in module not executed

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular8, angular-module

In Angular 8, i created a fresh module and put a new directive in. But at execution time nothing happen (compile is ok).

I putted console log in directive so see in different manner if it's executed but never, constructor never called.

```
<button button-confirmation></button>
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ButtonConfirmationComponent } from './component/button-confirmation.component';
import { ButtonConfirmationDirective } from './directive/button-confirmation.directive';

import {
  ConfirmationService,
  DomService
} from './services';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ButtonConfirmationComponent,
    ButtonConfirmationDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ConfirmationService,
    DomService
  ]
})
export class ButtonConfirmationModule { }
```

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[button-confirmation]'
})
export class ButtonConfirmationDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    console.log(el, 'test');
    el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
}
```

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...

    ButtonConfirmationModule
```

In other side, if i try ti use the component ButtonConfirmationComponent, i got the error

> 'app-button-confirmation' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'app-button-confirmation' is an Angular component bla bla bla

This component moved to the app to the module and worked before (nothing changed inside).

I followed lot of articles and angular site, all the same way, so i become crazy, why directive in module does'nt work ? Why the component not understanded ?

Maybe it helps, i use Material Angular.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you attach directive to HTML element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any **`Module/Components/Pipe/Directive`** in order to be seen and used by any Module, it need to be import/declare in its @NgModule class decorator, and it **only visible to that module**. ( It important to know that Components/Pipe/Directive can only be declared one time in only one module of the whole apps )

So in your case the **`ButtonConfirmationComponent`**, **`ButtonConfirmationDirective`** only visible to **`ButtonConfirmationModule`**, but not be seen by the **`AppModule`**.

Export the **`ButtonConfirmationComponent`** and **`ButtonConfirmationModule`** from  your **`ButtonConfirmationModule`** so whichever Module import **`ButtonConfirmationModule`**, those  two also be visible to them for use.

In your **`ButtonConfirmationModule`** :

```
exports : [
    ButtonConfirmationComponent,
    ButtonConfirmationDirective
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, was tested this before without result, i guess i miss something between tests.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a directive from a module in another module, you must export it.

The declaration tells Angular that the component or directive exists, the export tells Angular that you can access it from outside your module.

You can find more explanations [here](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)

But basically you need to modify this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ButtonConfirmationComponent } from './component/button-confirmation.component';
import { ButtonConfirmationDirective } from './directive/button-confirmation.directive';

import {
  ConfirmationService,
  DomService
} from './services';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ButtonConfirmationComponent,
    ButtonConfirmationDirective
  ],
  exports: [ // <-- here
    ButtonConfirmationDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ConfirmationService,
    DomService
  ]
})
export class ButtonConfirmationModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button ButtonConfirmationModule should exports components that will be used into other modules.

You have to update your module declaration

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ButtonConfirmationComponent } from './component/button-confirmation.component';
import { ButtonConfirmationDirective } from './directive/button-confirmation.directive';

import {
  ConfirmationService,
  DomService
} from './services';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ButtonConfirmationComponent,
    ButtonConfirmationDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ConfirmationService,
    DomService
  ],
  exports : [

// These items can be used outside this module
    ButtonConfirmationComponent,
    ButtonConfirmationDirective
  ]
})
export class ButtonConfirmationModule { }
```